# Unhide overlay menu after hiding it with javascript

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I've got my overlay menu, which I use a script to hide when clicked anywhere on the overlay container. My problem is, I can't sort of unhide if afterwards, so as soon as it is hidden with first the first click, I can't get it to show again. When I press the menu, it just shows nothing.

Any way to make it so it sorts of resets the event?

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.box', function () {
        $('.box').fadeOut( function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });

    });
});
```

Here is the js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sqfyrkpo/

Comment: Everything you said makes no sense, why hide a div AFTER you fadeOut (which equals hidden) ? To show a hidden div you need to use the exact opposite of the two, .hide()/.show(), .fadeOut()/.fadeIn()

Comment: By the way, the OP's fiddle will not work as he has not selected a version of JQuery to use. Select a JQuery version to get it to work. @Villads you may want to update this in your question fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want to hide and show the menu. Show on click of the menu input (which you currently do using the `:checked` pseudo class in CSS) and then hide when clicking the overlay box that appears?

If so, why not just uncheck the input using JQuery. This way the overlay will be controlled by the checkbox and the CSS essentially, using the JQuery to do so. Like this (using the basis of your code already):

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.box', function () {
        $('#toggle-nav').attr('checked', false);
    });
});
```

**Here is the updated fiddle to show you**:

http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/sqfyrkpo/7/

Also:

I think you were perhaps trying to overcomplicate it, using a checkbox to show using CSS and then using JQuery to hide, which are two different techniques-both separate and unknowing of each other.

Ideally the point of using a checkbox (hack) to toggle other CSS is to use the checkbox to toggle both states without the use of JQuery.

As you are using JQuery and the way in which you seem to want this to work, you might want to think about just using JQuery to handle all of this instead of part html checkbox (hack) part JQuery, by using a toggling class, say `active`, on your box (to show/hide the menu). This would give you much more flexibility of markup too and how you can structure your menu. Just an idea!

something like:

```
$(function () {
    $('#menuButton').on('click', function () {
        $('.box').toggleClass('active');
    });
    $('.box').on('click', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

and update the CSS to use the `active` class, similar to:

```
#menu .box.active
{ 
    opacity: 1; 
    z-index: 400;
}
```

(There are other updates to the CSS too in the example)

Here is an example with altered HTML, CSS and JQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/sqfyrkpo/18/

However that said, following the JQuery approach either way, then limits your users to have JQuery enabled to use the menu (strictly not fully accessible). So you might also want to think about how a user with no JS enabled could navigate the page.

Comment: Thanks for your help man! I got it all working now! Much appreciated!